# hibernate performance issue, persist one by one or mass?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, persistence

I have a text file ~6GB which I need to parse and later persist. By 'parsing' I'm reading a line from the file (usually 2000 chars), create a Car-object from the line and later I persist it.

I'm using a producer consumer pattern to parse and persist and wonder if it makes any difference (for performance reasons) to persist one object at a time or 1000 (or any other amount) in one commit?

At the moment, it takes me >2hr to persist everything (3 million lines) and it looks too much time for me (or I may be wrong).

Currently I'm doing this:

```
public void persistCar(Car car) throws Exception
{
    try
    {
        carDAO.beginTransaction();  //get hibernate session...

        //do all save here.

        carDAO.commitTransaction(); // commit the session

    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        carDAO.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
    finally
    {
        carDAO.close();
    }
}
```

Before I make any design changes I was wondering if there's a reason why this design is better (or not) and if so, what should be the cars.size()? Also, is open/close of session considered expensive?

```
public void persistCars(List<Car> cars) throws Exception
{
    try
    {
        carDAO.beginTransaction();  //get hibernate session...
        for (Car car : cars)    
        //do all save here.

        carDAO.commitTransaction(); // commit the session

    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        carDAO.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
    finally
    {
        carDAO.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Traditionally hibernate does not go that well with bulk inserts. There are some ways to optimize it to some level.

Take this example from the [API Docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-inserts),

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

for ( int i=0; i<100000; i++ ) {
    Customer customer = new Customer(.....);
    session.save(customer);
    if ( i % 20 == 0 ) { //20, same as the JDBC batch size
        //flush a batch of inserts and release memory:
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
    }
}

tx.commit();
session.close();
```

In the above example the session if flushed after inserting 20 entries which will make the operation little faster.

Here an [interesting article](http://abramsm.wordpress.com/2008/04/23/hibernate-batch-processing-why-you-may-not-be-using-it-even-if-you-think-you-are/) discussing the same stuff.

We have successfully implemented an alternative way of bulk inserts using stored procedures. In this case you will pass the parameters to the SP as "|" separated list, and will write the insert scrips inside the SP. Here the code might look a bit complex but is very effective.

Comment: I'll try this code for performance and get back to this answer. Thanks!